# No verification e-mail for Apple developer account

Tags: ios, apple-developer

I have purchased an individual membership developer account a week ago but I did not receive any membership confirmation e-mail yet. I got the invoice saying that I was charged the particular amount. I waited for a week till I receive the confirmation e-mail.

What is the exact procedure of purchasing the developer account? How long does it take to confirm my purchase? What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a technical question, and we're not the Apple support desk.

Comment: Ahem. Who has given this off-topic question two upvotes? `:-(`